# hover effect changing background image and content

Tags: css, haml, font-awesome

I'm kind of new at haml/css and i wanted to know if it was possible to do the following:
having an image with a font awesome icon over it. Then, on the hover effect, change the image and show, instead of the icon, some text. 
The image could be consider as a background image, but i couldn't figure out the rest.

haml:

```
.feature
      #dot
        %i.fa.fa-list-ul
```

css:

```
#dot{
    display: inline-block;
    background-image: url(../assets/blue.png);
    width: 29%;
    height: 102px;
}

#dot:hover{
    background: url(../assets/hover.png);
}
```

this just resolves the part of hover effect, but it's not showing my icon. I didn't even start with the text on the hover

Comment: give some code that you exactly tried

Comment: Could you provide a demo for us?

Comment: i've fixed it. i'm just waiting until tomorrow to post it because of my reputation score.

Answer (score 0):

Well.. i fixed it doing the following (in case somebody else is interested)

this is my haml:

```
.dot
        %i.fa.fa-list-ul
        .read_more Text on hover
```

this is my css:

```
.dot{
    display: inline-block;
    background-image: url(../assets/blue.png);
    width: 29%;
    height: 102px;
    -moz-transition: all 1s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
    transition: all 1s;
}
.dot i{
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transition: all 1s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
    transition: all 1s;
}
.dot .read_more{
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transition: all 1s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
    transition: all 1s;
}

.dot:hover{
    background: url(../assets/hover.png);
    -webkit-transition: all 1s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    -moz-transition: all 1s;
    transition: all 1s;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dot:hover i{
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transition: all 1s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    -webkit-transition: all 1s; 
    transition: all 1s;
}

.dot:hover .read_more{
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transition: all 1s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
    transition: all 1s;
}
```

the -moz and -webkit is used in order to be supported on all browsers.
the transition: all 1s, says the transition's effect should apply to all the elements and the time set it how long it will take to make the transition.

The opacity is just used as the visibility: hidden/visible, but in order to work with the transition attribute, one must change it to opacity.